# Return row IDs and 2 fields where the 2 fields are unique

Tags: mysql

I am looking for an efficient way to retrieve unique items with each relevant `id` in a MySQL query. The goal is explained below in an example table and desired output (shown as `json`). My progress so far is also below.

**Table**

```
+----+------+------+
| id | var1 | var2 |
+----+------+------+
| 1  | a    | b    |
+----+------+------+
| 2  | a    | c    |
+----+------+------+
| 3  | c    | b    |
+----+------+------+
| 4  | a    | c    |
+----+------+------+
| 5  | a    | b    |
+----+------+------+
```

**Desired Output**

```
{
    var1: a,
    var2: b,
    ids: 1,5
},
{
    var1: a,
    var2: c,
    ids: 2,4
}
```

So far I have this query which accurately returning rows matching where var1 and var2 are unique:

```
`SELECT base_currency,quote_currency FROM pf_items GROUP BY base_currency,quote_currency`
```

The problem I am having is also including the associated `id` fields as an array to achieve something close to the desired output above.

I have searched for answers to this problem, but describing exactly what I am trying to achieve with the result is hard without the above visualisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Revo's answer, if you are using MySQL 5.7 or above, you can output data directly in your expected JSON format, using `JSON_OBJECT` function :

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 'var1',var1, 'var2',var2 ,'ids', GROUP_CONCAT(id)) AS JSON 
FROM pf_items 
GROUP BY var1, var2
```

Returns

```
     {"ids": "1,5", "var1": "a", "var2": "b"}    
     {"ids": "2,4", "var1": "a", "var2": "c"}     
     {"ids": "3", "var1": "c", "var2": "b"}
```

See it live: http://rextester.com/live/BZDD55420

Answer (score 1):

To have a comma separated list of all `id`s beside using `group by`, you should select based on `group_concat`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) as ids, var1, var2 FROM pf_items GROUP BY var1, var2;
```